# Product image watermarks

Tags: magento-1.7, product-images

We're using an image tool to create product image watermarks, most marketing services (Google Merchant Center for example) do not approve of watermarked images.

Can anybody think of a method whereby product image watermarks could be removed automatically using Magento?

Also, would it be possible to do hotlink prevention on the images themselves?